# Antlr Lexer rule excluding tokens

Tags: antlr4, lexer

Here is a fragment from my ANTLR4 grammar:

Lexer Rules:

```
AND                 : ('a'|'A') ('n'|'N') ('d'|'D');
OR                  : ('o'|'O') ('r'|'R') ;
NOT                 : ('n'|'N') ('o'|'O') ('t'|'T') ;

TERM                : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|[1-9])+ ;
```

Parser Rules:

```
negation: NOT;
logical:  AND|OR;
term:     TERM;

search
   : negation? term (logical negation? term)* ;
   ;
```

Essentially I am trying to get it parse the **"you and me"** string such that the TERM token would match **"you"**, **"me"** and I would like **"and"** to be recognized by the AND rule, *not* the TERM rule.

Right now I am getting: `line 1:4 missing TERM at 'and'` error.

I understand that my input is being matched by both AND and TERM lexer rules, but I would like to be able to specify that TERM is anything *except* what matches AND rule.

Comment: You should consider using the 'literals' feature when you have this very typical keyword/identifier common prefix ambiguity in antlr.   (See http://www.antlr2.org/doc/options.html#literal)

Comment: Looks like you need to add a whitespace rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your lexer rules:

`WS : [ \r\n\t\u000C]+ -> skip ;`

Basically this is a token that matches any whitspace, tab, newline, tr and with `skip` you're telling ANTLR to skip it.